# Should I answer beginners' questions or simply downvote and flag them as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

Every day, I see a lot of questions on the same topics, for example:

- How to perform an Ajax call / how to regularly update data from a database on a page
- How to use dates in PHP or in MySQL
- How to reformat a PHP array

These kind of questions are asked many times, everyday, often from new users, who say right away that they are beginners in JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, etc.

Should I answer these questions? Or downvote them, and flag as duplicates?

Comment: If it's a duplicate, by all means find your canonical dupe and close against it. Then you've both closed and answered the question at the same time. What you do voting-wise is then up to you.

Comment: Dude, that's mean :P

Comment: __All questions should be answered if you can.__  Voting and Closing of the question is a separate issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you feel that the question does not show any research effort, that it is unclear, or that it is not useful, then downvoting it is appropriate.

If you feel that the question shows research effort, is useful, and clear, then upvoting it is appropriate.

If you have found a suitable duplicate then closing it accordingly is most certainly the best option; such a question should not be answered.

If the question is not a duplicate, but meets any other close criteria, you should vote/flag to close it as appropriate.

If it's a suitable question for the site, and you don't feel any type of closure is warranted, feel free to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

IMO

[image: flow chart]

Comment: How new a user isn't shouldn't affect how you vote on their posts.  Also, not all duplicate questions deserve downvotes.

Comment: @Servy IMO a new user should not get downvotes right away, that scares them away. Plus the close vote is enough to deliver the message. Again, IMO.

Comment: It is providing valuable feedback about the quality of their posts.  Feedback that is very important for both them, and many other users of the site.  If they aren't given the feedback that there are problems with their question then they will continue to post them.  Others are also not given the feedback that this question is of low quality and isn't worth their time to look at.  It prevents the eventual automatic deletion of the question if it really isn't of value to the site, etc.

Comment: @Servy you got a point, but you are forgetting that most of the downvoters do not comment the reasons behind their downvotes causing the new users to run away. So a comment or the close vote (which will automatically add a comment in case of closing for duplicate) is enough for new users IMO.

Comment: Downvoting in no way precludes commenting.  If you want to encourage commenting for new users, then say that, but not downvoting a post that, by your own admission, warrants downvoting, simply because the user is new, causes quite a lot of problems, it's just that those problems are much less apparent.

Comment: It depends on if the dupicate is easy to find, sometimes you can only find the dupicate becouse you know the answer, so I may close as dup AND upvote.